# How to use $1 twice

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to know how can I use the value of `(.*?)` twice?
for example:

```
$data = preg_replace("/<d>\s*(\s*(.*?)\s*)</d>/i", "F: $1, S: $1", $data);
```

this code above returns the value I use (for example: `Hello`) and returns:
`F: , S: Hello`, but I want it to return `F: Hello, S: Hello`

Here's the code that isn't working:

`"MySQLi\s*~\s*Escape\s*(\s*.*?\s*)", "$1 = mysql_real_escape_string$1", "MySQLi~Escape('Hi');"`
outputs:

```
 = mysql_real_escape_string('Hi');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `U` modifier.

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b5126fa87d68a780a3a7b5b946523c7402a853b):

```
$res = preg_replace("/MySQLi\s*~\s*Escape\s*((\s*.*?\s*))/U", "$1 = mysql_real_escape_string$2", "MySQLi~Escape('Hi');");
var_dump($res);
```

output:

```
string(41) "('Hi'); = mysql_real_escape_string('Hi');"
```

From the [official PHP's documentations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)**
>
> This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so that they are not greedy by default, but become greedy if followed by ?. It
>   is not compatible with Perl. It can also be set by a (?U) modifier
>   setting within the pattern or by a question mark behind a quantifier
>   (e.g. .*?).

Comment: `"MySQLi\s*~\s*Escape\s*(\s*.*?\s*)", "$1 = mysql_real_escape_string$1", "MySQLi~Escape('Hi');"`
outputs:
 = mysql_real_escape_string('Hi');

Comment: that wasn't me, it helped me